# Angular5 - disable mat-list-option

Tags: angular-material, angular5

I use this code in my Angular5 application:

```
<mat-selection-list>
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let activityType of activityTypes" [selected]="isActivityTypeSelected(activityType)" (click)="addSelectedActivityType(activityType)">{{activityType | translate}}</mat-list-option>
 </mat-selection-list>
```

and in some cases I will disable the **mat-list-option**. Therefore I tried it like this ([disabled]="closedCalendarEvent"):

```
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let activityType of activityTypes" [selected]="isActivityTypeSelected(activityType)" (click)="addSelectedActivityType(activityType)" [disabled]="closedCalendarEvent">{{activityType | translate}}</mat-list-option>
```

but it does not work, thd checkboxes are still clickable.
Does anyone know what I can do in order to disable the checkboxes of **mat-list-option**?

Comment: Please post your code for`closedCalendarEvent` - there is no obvious reason why it shouldn't work. As a test, try `[disabled]="true"`.

Comment: The problem was that I also listened to (click) events and that worked fine although [disabled] was true.

Comment: @quma, did you ever figure out how to get it working? I am having similar problem.